# array used the same memory space?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory

i have an array in the main program like this: (i am using C# to program in asp.net)

```
double[][] example= new double[][];
```

for this example lets imagine is an array of 10*2.

so next thing i will do is send this array to another function like this:

```
usedarray(example);
public double[][] usedarray(double[][]examplearray)
{

}
```

i know that a double array in each space has only 64 bit floating point number, so the array will have a 1280 bits for this example used memory, but when is send to the function it used the same space of memory? or it use a complete new set of memory space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, not value types.  That means that the variable, `examplearray` doesn't actually contain 1280 bits of data, it just contains a reference (sometimes also referred to as a pointer) to the actual data, which is stored elsewhere (for the purposes of this post, it doesn't matter where "elsewhere" actually is).  Passing that variable to a method, as you have done there, is only copying that reference (which is 32 or 64 bits, depending on the system), not the underlying 1280 bits of data.

Comment: that it thit not know thanks for your anwser, now the problem is how can i find out how many memory is been used by this array, i was under the impression since a double has a 64 bits meany of life so an array in each space will have the same 64 bits

Comment: @JUAN Well, what you have is an array of arrays, not just a single array, so `example` points to a structure that contains a number of other references to other arrays.  The size of a reference is 32 or 64 bits.  Once you create that many other arrays (you aren't doing that yet) then each of those references will point to another data structure that contains a bit of header information and then also X * 64 bits, where X is the size of that array.  That's where the actual data is.

Comment: @Servi yes i didt not write the creation of the array so the next thig to do is  inseide  a for 'example[N]=new double[2]' so i will have:  a 'example[N][0], example[N][1]' this will mean that each of them has only 64 bit a total of 64*N?